# loading json files using json normalize + pd concat

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

someone would help me optimize my solution of loading data from json files using json normalize and pd concat?
My 5k json files like:

```
[
  {
    "id": {
      "number": 2121",
      "exp" : "1",
      "state": "California"
      },
    "state": [
      {
        "city": "San Francisco",
        "pm": "17",
        "spot": "2"
      },
      {
        "city": "San Diego",
        "pm": "14",
        "spot": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": {
      "number": "2122",
      "exp" : "1"
      "state": "California",
    },
    "state": [
      {
        "city: "San Jose",
        "pm": "15",
        "spot": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have to load data from 'state' and I must have the date (taken from json file name) on each city. My solution is

```py
json_paths = 'my files_directory' 

jsfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(json_paths, "*.json"))

main_df = pd.DataFrame() 

for file in jsfiles:

    df = pd.read_json(file)

    for i in df['state']:

        df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(i))], ignore_index=False, sort = False)
        df2['date'] = file 
        main_df = pd.concat([main_df, df2])
```

Loading 1000 jsons takes a long time, let alone 5000. Is there any way to optimize my solution?

Comment: Do your transformations before you load it into pandas. Your current method takes a long time because appending rows to a dataframe requires copying all the data each time you append/concat (they are fixed length numpy arrays, but then you want to append, which requires making a new array). Get everything into a list with the structure you want (maybe a list of dicts, where each dict maps the column name to the value for that row---but you can do this other ways, too). Then just `DataFrame` that whole list.

Comment: Alkasm, thank you for your advice. Could you see my code below?

Comment: Please add your new code to your OP. To comment, you're still using `pd.read_json` which you shouldn't be using at all. Use the normal `json` module in Python to read the JSON file. Only use `pd.read_json` if your JSON file is already in a compatible format for Pandas, like an array of flat objects, which yours isn't.

Comment: Your JSON in the OP is badly formed, as there's not a comma after the first object in the array closes. It is unclear whether or not each JSON file is an array of objects, or if each file is just an object. I assumed the first in my answer, but please update your OP with more info on your files if that's not correct.

Comment: Yes, of course, there was my mistake in JSON. Your assumption of the answer is correct and your answer is great. This is what I want! 
I'm new to the world of Data Science, so thank you for all advice. It definitely comes in handy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the functions you are using seem convoluted for this purpose because they somewhat are. `json_normalize()` is for flattening a dictionary (removing nesting) which you don't need to do since your JSON state object is already flat. Using `pd.read_json` is fine if your JSON file is already in a convenient format for reading, but yours isn't.

With those things in mind, the easiest thing to do is to parse each JSON file first in Python so that you get the data that you want to correspond to a single row into a dictionary, and keep a list of all of those.

Also I used `pathlib.Path` objects to clean up globbing and filename extraction.

Something like this is what you want to do:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import json

# each dict in states corresponds to a row
states = []

# you can glob directly on pathlib.Path objects
for file in Path("my files_directory").glob("*.json"):

    # load json data
    with open(file) as jsonf:
        data = json.load(jsonf)

    # add the date from the filename stem to each dict, and append to list
    for result in data:
        for state in result["state"]:
            state["date"] = file.stem
            states.append(state)

# create a df where each row corresponds to each dict in states
df = pd.DataFrame(states)
```